# How to acquire adjacency matrix of a subgraph returned by JanusGraph Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I used this query to get 3-hopped subgraph of a designated node

```
subgraph = g.V().has('customer', 'id', '528311').repeat(bothE().subgraph('subGraph').otherV()).times(3).cap('subGraph').next()
```

I want to get the adjacency matrix of this subgraph so that I can feed it in spectral clustering model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no shortcuts really to generate an adjacency matrix from a graph with TinkerPop (perhaps that should be rectified). You basically just need to construct one yourself, which isn't too hard - I will use the "modern" graph as an example:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> count = g.V().order().by('name').store('x').
......1>           property('oid',union(select('x').count(local),
......2>                                constant(-1)).sum()).
......3>           count().next()
==>6
```

I added an "oid" property value that is just a custom id that increments from zero using a custom sort format for the data so that it's easy to align to the structure of the matrix, where the "oid" will align to the position of the rows and columns in the data:

```
gremlin> g.V().elementMap()
==>[id:1,label:person,name:marko,oid:2,age:29]
==>[id:2,label:person,name:vadas,oid:5,age:27]
==>[id:3,label:software,name:lop,oid:1,lang:java]
==>[id:4,label:person,name:josh,oid:0,age:32]
==>[id:5,label:software,name:ripple,oid:4,lang:java]
==>[id:6,label:person,name:peter,oid:3,age:35]
```

Then I construct a matrix of bytes given the number of vertices:

```
gremlin> matrix = new byte[count][count]
==>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
==>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
==>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
==>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
==>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
==>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Finally, I go through each edge to update the matrix as a side-effect. I opted to convert each `Edge` to a `Map` so that it would be easy to deduplicate multiple edges between vertices and perhaps more clearly demonstrate the update to the matrix itself:

```
gremlin> g.E().project('out','in').
......1>         by(outV().values('oid')).
......2>         by(inV().values('oid')).
......3>   dedup().
......4>   each {
......5>     matrix[(int) it['out']][(int) it['in']] = 1
......6>   }
gremlin> matrix
==>[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
==>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
==>[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
==>[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
==>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
==>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```